# How to compile php with all options on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php

I installed LAMP on ubuntu.
But it has only basic setting with php.
i want to recompile php with all options

HOw can i recompile php using /configure

I used to compile and build using cpanel easy apache . it has all the options and i usually checked that.

Now i have the full command text of cpanel php build which i want to use

```
'./configure' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-zend-multibyte' '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-curlwrappers' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mhash=/opt/mhash/' '--with-mime-magic' '--with-mm=/opt/mm/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pgsql=/usr' '--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-sqlite=shared' '--with-ttf' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
```

Can i just copy and paste that and it will gave me the same option as php build by cpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install package1 package2 package3` and so forth will allow you to perform multiple package installs at once so that you don't have to use this roundabout fashion of avoiding one-by-one package installs.

Comment: Or you can use aptitude.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you compiling php? Is there something wrong with the php that you can install from the Ubuntu repositories? Unless there's a very good reason to install from source, you'll save yourself many headaches going forward by just installing as many packages as possible via synaptic/apt-get/etc.

If you need additional modules for php, nearly all that you may need are available in the apt repositories.

What specific modules do you require?

Comment: Actually i need pear , pdo for postgresql , mysqli , mcrypt , curl , soap etc.

Now i have to do this very often on diff machines so if the aboove configure method works then i can just copy and paste and then all configuration will be done , othwise i have to install each pacakage one by one

Comment: You know you can just request all the modules with a single apt-get right?

Comment: no i didn't knw that , whhat is that command

Comment: See my added answer.